# Group product of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

If $G=\langle g \rangle$ and $H=\langle h \rangle$, show that $G\times H=\langle(g,1),(1,h)\rangle$.

I don't really know what it is I am supposed to do. My guess is that I let $G$ be defined as above then somehow show that $G=\{(g_1,1),(g_2,1)\dots\}$, but I don't know how to do so.

Comment: Note that this is not just a "Cartesian product", but a _group product_ (which is a particular rule for how to make a Cartesian product of groups into a group itself).

Comment: I will edit the title, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, by definition,
$$
G\times H = \{(g,h): g\in G, h\in H\}.
$$
This is a group under the operation $$(g,h)(g',h') = (gg', hh').$$
Clearly, then,
$$
\langle(g,1), (h,1)\rangle \subseteq G\times H .
$$
You just need to prove that $\langle(g,1), (h,1)\rangle \supseteq G\times H$. 
Now let $(g,h)\in G\times H$. Well, then $(g,h) = (g,1)(1,h)$, so ...